# Cannot set property of undefined ionic in function

Tags: ionic3

error : Cannot set property x2 of undefined in function to use

```
  x2 : string;
  const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
  const results = provider.search({query : this.city}).then( function(e){
    console.log("function(e)",e[0]);
    this.x2=e[0].x;
  });
```

Comment: Update question with your complete component code

Answer (score 0):

Ok

```
x2 : string;
const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();
const results = provider.search({query : this.city}));

results.then( (e) => {
  console.log("function(e)",e[0]);
  this.x2=e[0].x;
}
```